# Move constructor and assignment operator: why no default for derived classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

Why there is default move constructor or assignment operator not created for derived classes?  To demonstrate what I mean; having this setup code:

```
#include <utility>

struct A
{
  A () { }
  A (A&&) { throw 0; }
  A& operator= (A&&) { throw 0; }
};

struct B : A
{ };
```

either of the following lines throws:

```
A  x (std::move (A ());
A  x;  x = A ();
```

but neither of the following does:

```
B  x (std::move (B ());
B  x;  x = B ();
```

In case it matters, I tested with GCC 4.4.

EDIT: Later test with GCC 4.5 showed the same behavior.

Comment: Does the `std::move` change anything here? Isn't `A()` already an rvalue?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Otherwise C++ standard allows compiler to compress that into just-construct-x (or so I was told on freenode.net).  I also verified that without `std::move` the move constructor is not trigerred, so freenode.net's comment appears to be true.

Comment: @Mike: Copy elision (12.8/34, 0x FCD) is a common optimization, but using move() makes this expression fall outside the permitted circumstances.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right!  So it's still a move in the sense that the move ctor needs to be accessible, but the actual call gets elided, just like a call to the copy ctor would.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading through 12.8 in the 0x FCD (12.8/17 in particular for the move ctor), this appears to be a GCC bug.  I see the same thing happening in 4.5 as you do in 4.4.

I may be missing a corner case on deleted functions, or something similar, but I don't see any indication of that yet.

Comment: Just tested with 4.5, I get the same results.  Can you test on any other compiler?  (Given that C++0x is in no way finished, it might be not a bug but rather an outdated behavior, by the way.)

Comment: A bunch of stuff in 12.8 (originating in N3053) isn't supported in `gcc` yet, according to their [C++0x support page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) - could this be the issue?

Comment: @douplep: If the goal is to support what the 0x FCD says, then it's a bug even if it originates from outdated behavior. :)

Comment: @Roger: Yeah, probably you are right.  I guess we can settle on your answer if anyone can verify that default move constructor/assignment is implicitly added on any other compiler.

Comment: @doublep: Why is it required that another compiler does it correctly, to say that GCC is not following the FCD?

Comment: @Roger: Because I'm not smart enough to understand standard just like that ;)

Comment: @Roger: It turned out I had an outdated draft, so I didn't quite understand your answer.  After reading the clause you mentioned in the current draft it is clear.  Thank you.